# How to send a selected collectionview cell to another view controller (ios)?

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm being able to detect the selected row (image) in my collection view, But I need to send it to another view controller. Here is a part of the code :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell {

        cell.cellImage.image = UIImage(named: images[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    } else {
        return CollectionViewCell()

    }
}

//Printinig the selected image ID in console
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    SelectedItem = indexPath.row + 1
    print(SelectedItem)
}

//Navigate to MPViewController
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let DestViewController = segue.destination as!  MPViewController
    DestViewController.labelText = String(SelectedItem)
}
}
```

Comment: Do you want to send the contents of that cell in the next view controller?

Comment: yes .. I would like to do so

Comment: what content do you want to send to DestViewController ?? is this label text or image ?

Comment: The collection view has 13 images, each image is on a row. I want to move to the next view controller when tapping on a specific image sending the row number of the row (the image) that is was tapped. I am trying to send the info after saving it in thel (abelText).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize a variable first

var imageToPass: UIImage!

Then update didSelectItemAt func

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    SelectedItem = indexPath.row + 1
    print(SelectedItem)

    self.imageToPass = UIImage(named: images[SelectedItem])

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "TargetVC", sender: imageToPass) //here you give the identifier of target ViewController
}
```

Go to your TargetVC and initialize a variable

var getImage: UIImage!

Then override the function in previous VC

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "TargetVC" {

            if let targetVC = segue.destination as? TargetVC {

                if let imageToPass = sender as? UIImage {

                    TargetVC.getImage = imageToPass

                }

            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take one instance variable in your destination class and set value of it in prepare for segue and then in `viewDidload` set that string to your label's text like,

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let DestViewController = segue.destination as!  MPViewController
    DestViewController.yourText = String(SelectedItem) 
 }
```

ans in `viewDidload`

```
  yourLabel.text = yourText
```

Comment: You are still wrong, view did load is not called so the label won't be updated ;)

Comment: I am just trying to make questioner a scenario. Yes, he should take one instance variable to getting string and in viewDidload he can set that to label! btw edited my answer! thanks for suggesion! @PankajTeckchandani

Answer (score 0):

```
//Printinig the selected image ID in console

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    self.SelectedItem = indexPath.row + 1

    self.selectedImage = UIImage(named: images[indexPath.row]);

    print(SelectedItem)
}

//Navigate to MPViewController
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let DestViewController = segue.destination as!  MPViewController
    DestViewController.imageSelected = self.selectedImage;
    DestViewController.selectedItem = String(self.SelectedItem);

}
```

Now in MPViewController you can use the data self.imageSelected and self.selectedItem as per your requirements.